# Why are SQL statements divided into DDL, DML, DCL and TCL statements?

Tags: sql

Are there specific needs for these statements to be divided into groups, or is this done  to logically term the various types of statements (in discussions, reference documentation, etc.)?

Are there use cases where it would be important to segregate these statements into these sub groupings?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there's any practical reason, aside from defining the terms.

Comment: Notable nonconstructive question, suckahs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are classifications, they exits for the same reason every other classification on anything else exists...

Regarding use cases, I hardly see a situation where you would use those terms but maybe if you are the Business Analyst for a SQL Server management tool you could say that you dont want users to have access to any sort of DDL statments, meaning the users cant create objects on the DB...

Answer (score 7):

DDL (Data Definition Language) --> Used for defining data structures and schema like Create and Alter commands.

DML (Data Manipulation Language) --> Used for managing data with schema objects like Select commands.

DCL (Data Control Language) --> Used to control data like Revoke and Grant commands.

TCL (Transaction Control Language) --> Used to manage the changes made by DML statements like Commit.

These are the classifications.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need as such.

But it does provide a handle when discussing SQL. I regularly use DML and DDL as shorthand.

Example:

> MySQL doesn't support transactional DDL but SQL Server does.

Everyone (hopefully) knows what you mean without saying

> MySQL doesn't support transactional CREATE, ALTER and DROP statements...

What they mean: http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands

Answer (score 1):

They are not divided. They are classified into types depending on the type of operations they perform on the database.