# What is the meaning of derived the data definition language code(TSQL) from the model

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a assignment question and I can't understand the question, please help me to understand the question,

here is the question

> Implement the model above as a SQLServer 2012 database schema & associated tables. Document your solution by reproducing the SQLServer Database Diagram. **Select two associated tables and show how you derived the Data Definition Language code (T-SQL) from the model.** If you built the tables using the Visual Designer you must script the tables and relate your model to the generated code.

I have already draw the EER diagram and wrote the 'create table' queries, but what I can't understand is the bold line in the question

what is the meaning of it, am I already done ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question you need to understand what `DDL` is.

Here is definition from MSDN

> Data Definition Language (DDL) is a vocabulary used to define data
>   structures in SQL Server 2012. Use these statements to create, alter,
>   or drop data structures in an instance of SQL Server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx

So anything that you write to create, drop or alter structure is DDL. So you just need to show how you came up with `CREATE TABLE` script.

Check out Microsoft Virtual Academy.

Here is slide from [Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Databases Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/querying-microsoft-sql-server-2012-databases-jump-start)

[image]

Comment: why they mention (T-SQL) inside the brackets after DDL, is there anything related to T-SQL in DDL

Comment: DDL, DML and DCL is all part of T-SQL it is just divided to **sections or categories** depending on what that T-SQL is used for. This might clarify it for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803047/why-are-sql-statements-divided-into-ddl-dml-dcl-and-tcl-statements/12803155#12803155

Comment: then I guess I have already done.. coz I have written the table create scripts, isn't it ???

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for upvote your answer.. but here is my +1, thanks lot.